# Unable to find electron-prebuilt's version number. - When trying to use electron-rebuild

Tags: node.js, electron

I am trying to use bluetooth-serial-port native module in electron (atom-shell). I did the following.

1. Installed electron-prebuilt.

`npm install electron-prebuilt -g
npm install electron-prebuilt --save-dev`

2. Installed electron-rebuild

`npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild`

3. Installed bluetooth-serial-port

`npm install bluetooth-serial-port --msvs_version=2013`

4. Running electron-rebuild command.

`./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild`

and I am getting the following error.

> Unable to find electron-prebuilt's version number, either install it or specify an explicit version"

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5):

Install the electron-prebuilt on the same folder level.

Comment: I installed both with `npm install --save-dev`, yet I have the same error.

Comment: I have the same issue. Folder level isn't the issue i think

Answer (score 2):

In the root folder of your project, use this:

`node_modules/.bin/electron -v`

If you're on a Windows machine, use back slashes in the path.

`node_modules\.bin\electron -v`

This is what mine looks like: `v0.28.3`

Answer (score 1):

You can see your electron version number by running electron with no arguments..

Example:

```
cd ./my_project
npm install --save-dev electron-prebuilt
node_modules/.bin/electron
```

You should get a little welcome notice that displays your version number.

If you've installed electron pre-built globally, just run the 'electron' command for the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I found my electron version by running `npm list electron`:

```
`-- electron@26.0.0
```

Then I specified the version number in the command:
`./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild -f -w 26.0.0`

This solved the issue for me.